# sum and group by do not work in android roomdatabase Kotlin

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, group-by, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a roomdatabase with 4 tables, I want to use GROUP BY and also SUM both in ONE query.
so what I had done till now:

```
@Query("SELECT *, SUM(increase) FROM transactions GROUP BY user_id")
fun groupBy(): LiveData<List<Transactions>>?
```

But `SUM` doesnt work(It shows the first increase by user_id.
For instanse: I have 2 users named MAX and Amir with user id 1 and 2

***Amir(userId 1) submit 100$ increase and again 50$ increase.***
***Max(userId2) submit 80$ increase and again 10$ increase.***

Please look at the result:

```
D/TAG: groupBy: 1  100
D/TAG: groupBy: 2  80
```

It supposed to show:

```
D/TAG: groupBy: 1  150
D/TAG: groupBy: 2  90
```

one point:
I have a field in database that named trans_id which stands for transactionId.
Each time I submit increase or decrease or anything else thet related to user and money my app automaticly genereates one id and it is transactionId each time it autmaticly generate transactionId but It is not as same as last one.
Where I use It?
When I want to get all user's transactions

Function where I read data from(in user list fragment):

```
 private fun groupBy() {
    mUserListViewModel.groupBy()?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        mUserListViewModel.group.value = it
        it.forEach {
            Log.d("TAG", "groupBy: ${it.userId} // ${it.increase}")
         }
    })
}
```

My viewModel:

```
 val group = MutableLiveData<List<Transactions>>()
fun groupBy(): LiveData<List<Transactions>>? { 
    return mTransactionDAO.groupBy()
}
```

Data class:

```
data class Transactions(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "trans_id")
    var transId: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id", index = true) // <<<<< best to have an index on the column, not required
    var userId: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "create_date")
    var createDate: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bank_id")
    var bankId: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "increase")
    var increase: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "decrease")
    var decrease: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "loan_number")
    var loanNumber: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total")
    var total: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    var type: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "loan_id")
    var loanId: Long?
)
```

***[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5MPf.png)***

**If you need more code, let me know in comments section**

Comment: Post the code that reads the results of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not read the summed `increase` but the column `increase` of your table because you use `*` which selects all the columns.

The correct way to write the query is:

```
@Query("SELECT user_id, SUM(increase) AS increase FROM transactions GROUP BY user_id")
fun groupBy(): LiveData<List<userTotals>>?
```

so that you get 2 columns: the `user_id` and the the total of increase aliased as `increase`.

You also need to create a new class for the results of the query:

```
data class userTotals(val user_id: Long?, val increase: Long?)
```

Comment: Yes your right but if I do not use * instead of user_id I would get error

Comment: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [transId]

Comment: I just edited question, please take look

Comment: transaction_id can not be nullable at all

Comment: when a user submit increase, transaction id auto genrate that transactionid in database

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper I see the code that you added, but this has nothing to do with the query. Your query should return each user_id with the total of increase. Nothing more. What transaction id do you want in the results? Each user has more than 1 transaction ids.

Comment: wait a sec. i will show you my database

Comment: I edited mu Q. look at the end of Q Mydatabase

Comment: I want to get all user increase and id of that user

Comment: look at table and imagin that user 3 increased 3 times and in table there would be 3 records. I WANT TO get that user id and sum all user increase

Comment: for example:   user_id 3   submit  150 increase

Comment: Anyway thanks for  spending time on this Q

Comment: I am going to up vote your answer but not accepted

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper Post your expected results from the query.

Comment: @Query("SELECT user_id, SUM(increase) FROM transactions GROUP BY user_id")
                         I it is completly true and what I WANTED but here BECAUSE trans_id, it didnt work and shows error(I have posted error in second comments)

Comment: trans_id can not be null at all

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper *but here BECAUSE trans_id it didnt work and shows error* there is no trans_id in the query and it is **not** needed for the query. If you get an error it comes from a different part of your code.

Comment: when I add yout query, error apear

Comment: wait a second pl

Comment: /home/amirhossein/Desktop/holy-quran-main/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/holyquran/data/database/TransactionsDAO.java:103: error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [transId] in com.example.holyquran.data.model.Transactions even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [user_id,increase]
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.example.holyquran.data.model.Transactions>> groupBy();

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper I see what you mean. You need a new class for the results of the query that will contain only 2 columns. See my edited answer.

Comment: or I can do sth else.  I can make transaction_id null able and each time user wants to increase, I add transaction_id manualy

Comment: by getting last trans_id from data base and increase it 1.  for example last transaction is 1 so I GET 1  from database and add  one.  like this: trans_id++

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper I would not suggest that. The Transactions class is fine as it is. It refers to your table's behavior. You should not change it. For each query that you create, that returns  a different type of data just create the corresponding class.

Comment: ya that is good idea i am gonna try your answer

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper no there is no need for a join. I did not change the query. All you need is a new class with only 2 columns/fields because the query returns only 2 columns. This class should be used here: `LiveData<List<userTotals>>?`

Comment: can u please upvote Q?

Comment: hey what AS do here?

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper it is used to alias the column SUM(increase) so that you can refer to it by the name `increase` (if you want you can change the name to total_increase or something else).

Comment: You are so kind and responseble Thanks for sharing your kwnolage with an Iranian developer

Comment: hey @forpas can you please take look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616974/data-from-database-dont-show-in-recycler-view-kotlin

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper I can't help you with Android code, but I think that you forgot to write `@ColumnInfo(name = "total")` in the `UserAndMoney` class.

Answer (score 2):

When you use group by clause then column name is required  remove * and add specific column name like this.

```
@Query("SELECT user_id, SUM(increase) FROM transactions GROUP BY user_id")
fun groupBy(): LiveData<List<Transactions>>?
```